# Changing background color in wordpress with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently trying to design a page on WordPress in  which I would like to implement a night-mode.

Basically, when you press a button(image), the background color will change from white to black (later on, also the text color).

I have to use inline-css and JavaScript because of WordPress.
Right now, I am trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var activated = 0; 
function changeBgCol() 
{ 
    if (activated == 0) 
    { 
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
         document.body.style.color = "white"; 
         activated = 1; 
     } 
     else 
     {  
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
         document.body.style.color = "black"; 
         activated = 0; 
     } 
}
</script>
```

and the button(image):

```
<a><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2591" onclick="javascript:changeBgColor()" src="https://www.[WEBSITE].se/main/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/[PICTURE]-300x300.png"  width="480" height="480" /></a>
```

But when I test, it, the image is not clickable and the background color doesnt change.

What could be the issue?

Best regards

Comment: Check console. `changeBgColor` and `changeBgCol`.

Comment: WordPress isn't relevant in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to toggle a class on the body.

```
$('.yourbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('theme--dark');
});
```

Then just add the corresponding CSS.

```
.theme--dark {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Comment: where would I implement 

 
`$('.yourbutton').on('click', function() {$('body').toggleClass('theme--dark'); }); ` ?

Comment: You can put this in your JS file, or in a script tag in your footer.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You had the onClick event set to changeBgColor, and the function in the JavaScript set to changeBgCol. Always check your developer console whenever you run into problems getting a script to work. Try this:

```
<a><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2591" onclick="javascript:changeBgCol()" src="https://www.[WEBSITE].se/main/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/[PICTURE]-300x300.png"  width="480" height="480" /></a>

<script>
    var activated = 0;

    function changeBgCol() {
        if (activated == 0) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.body.style.color = "white";
            activated = 1;
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.body.style.color = "black";
            activated = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's not generally considered best practice to use inline scripts. You might want to try something like this instead going forward: https://jsfiddle.net/eL46ch5y/ or use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Thank you! WordPress doesnt have a console I believe so I missed this!

Comment: I'm referring to your browsers developer console! https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console